# Python pyserial

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder, pyserial

I am triggering a device called olfactometer from python 2.7 anaconda spyder 64 bit. There are eight solenoid TTL valves in that olfactometer. If I want to switch the status of that valve I just have to write below-mentioned code.

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("COM3", 19200, timeout=0.5)
#turn on port 2, sleep 2 seconds, turn off port 2
port.write(b"\nF2\r")  # if opened then close port 2
time.sleep(2.0)
port.write(b"\nF2\r")  # if closed then open port 2


#close the port
port.close()
```

I would like to know, is it possible to give port 2 specific values from 0 or 1?

for example

```
if 'e' in keypress: 
    # it must open the port 2
if 'i' in keypress:
    # it must close the port 2
```

What should I do to perform the test in an above-mentioned way? 
Thank you in advance! 
- Ravi

Comment: it seems like your command `port.write(b'\nF2\r')` simply toggles the solenoid, so I would suggest perhaps prompting the user at the beginning what the state is, and keeping track of how many times it has been toggled so if the user asks to open it and it's already open, it doesn't then close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can capture input is with the [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) built-in function (`input` in Python3). For example

```
port = serial.Serial("COM3", 19200, timeout=0.5)

prompt = 'Press "e" to open, "i" to close, and "q" to quit: '
keypress = raw_input(prompt)
while keypress != 'q':
    if keypress == 'e':
        port.write(b"\nF2\r")  # if closed then open port 2
        print('Opened')
    elif keypress == 'i':
        port.write(b"\nF2\r")  # if opened then close port 2
        print('Closed')
    # prompt again    
    keypress = raw_input(prompt)

port.close()
```

Comment: Note, there are a lot of higher-level libraries to handle user prompts in a CLI. For example, [prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit)